# How to create anime speed lines in shader code?

Tags: unity-game-engine, shader, hlsl

*I am using an unlit shader in Unity (Universal Render Pipeline) with HLSL.*

**The Aim**

I am trying to create anime speed lines, similar to the picture below.

[image]

**The Problem**

I don't know how to proceed from this point (see below).
[image]

The code that creates this line is below, mostly found by accident when messing with shaping a line.

```
half4 frag(Varyings IN) : SV_Target
{
     float blendFactor = smoothstep(0.02, _LineWidth, abs(IN.uv.y - IN.uv.x));
     return pow(IN.uv.x * blendFactor, 10) * _LineColor;              
}
```

I think that a radial function or noise function is an approach that could work, however I have no idea how to implement that.

**Full Script**

```
Shader "Magnality/Speedlines"
{
    Properties
    {
        _LineColor("Line Color", Color) = (1, 1, 1, 1)
        _Speed("Speed", Float) = 1.0
        _Density("Density", Float) = 0.5
        _LineWidth("Line Width", Float) = 0.003

        [HideInInspector] _MainTex ("Texture", 2D) = "white" {}
    }
SubShader
{
    Tags { "RenderType"="Overlay" "RenderPipeline" = "UniversalPipeline" }
    LOD 100

    Pass
    {

        HLSLPROGRAM
        #pragma vertex vert
        #pragma fragment frag

        #include "Packages/com.unity.render-pipelines.universal/ShaderLibrary/Core.hlsl"

        struct Attributes
        {
            float4 positionOS : POSITION;
            float2 texcoord : TEXCOORD0;
        };

        struct Varyings
        {
            float4 positionHCS  : SV_POSITION;
            float4 positionOS   : TEXCOORD1;
            float2 uv           : TEXCOORD0;
            float4 screenPos    : TEXCOORD2;
        };

        Varyings vert(Attributes IN)
        {
            Varyings OUT;
            OUT.positionHCS = TransformObjectToHClip(IN.positionOS.xyz);
            OUT.positionOS = IN.positionOS;
            OUT.uv = IN.texcoord;

            OUT.screenPos = ComputeScreenPos(OUT.positionHCS);

            return OUT;
        }

        CBUFFER_START(UnityPerMaterial)

        half4 _LineColor;
        float _Speed;
        float _Density;
        float _LineWidth;

        CBUFFER_END

        half4 frag(Varyings IN) : SV_Target
        {
            float blendFactor = smoothstep(0.02, _LineWidth, abs(IN.uv.y - IN.uv.x));
            return pow(IN.uv.x * blendFactor, 10) * _LineColor;
        }
        ENDHLSL
    }
  }
}
```

Any advice is much appreciated.

Comment: Honestly not sure if SO is the best place to answer your question. Try looking for a different forum.

Comment: Yeah try reddit https://www.reddit.com/r/Unity3D/comments/scdyls/procedural_anime_speed_lines_postprocessing/